# Big-Theta , Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I've a question about this :

```
log_{b}(n) = Theta(log_{a}(n)) b,a >1
```

can i prove this with a condition of when : b >= a or the opposite also : b <= a  , where each of them will be used in each part of the Theta proof, 
(Big Omega and Big O ) ?

Comment: Maybe so. This is more appropriate for [cstheory.se].

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know that , thanks for the hint

Comment: Actually, theoretical CS is the wrong site for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a video that might help to Prove Big Theta:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vzqaz4MDGvc&t=3s

Basically all you need to do is substitute your functions for his. 
So f(n) = log_{b}(n) and g(n) = log_{a}(n).

I hope that helps you man, he has a lot of good videos on algorithm analysis and proving asymptotics like Big o, Big Theta, and big Omega.